# Custom ML function not working: undefined columns selected

Tags: r, machine-learning, rlang

I am trying to write a custom function to do logistic regression-based ML with the `caTools` package, but I keep getting the error: `undefined columns selected`.

I checked the input to `xlearn` and `ylearn` arguments to the `logit_boost` function and, as explained in the documentation, they are respectively dataframe containing feature and a vector of labels. So not sure what I am doing wrong.

```r
# needed libraries
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(caTools)

# function body
logit_boost <- function(data, x, y, split_size = 0.8) {
  # creating a dataframe
  data <-
    dplyr::select(.data = data,
                  !!rlang::enquo(x),
                  !!rlang::enquo(y))

  # for reproducibility
  set.seed(123)

  # creating indices to choose rows from the data
  train_indices <-
    base::sample(x = base::seq_len(length.out = nrow(data)),
                 size = floor(split_size * nrow(data)))

  # training dataset
  train <- data[train_indices, ]

  # testing dataset
  test <- data[-train_indices, ]

  # defining label column we are interested in and everything else
  label_train <-
    train %>% dplyr::select(.data = ., !!rlang::enquo(x))

  data_train <-
    train %>% dplyr::select(.data = ., -!!rlang::enquo(x))

  # training model (y ~ x)
  logit_model <-
    caTools::LogitBoost(xlearn = data_train,
                        ylearn = label_train)

  # prediction
  # stats::predict(object = logit_model, test, type = "raw")
}

logit_boost(data = mtcars, x = am, y = mpg)
#> Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)): undefined columns selected
```

Comment: Check the classes of the different columns. I've seen similar errors in other cases when one of the columns has been converted to a factor.

Comment: No, I checked the structure and it's of `numeric` type so that doesn't seem to be the issue. Additionally, `caTools::LogitBoost` documentation states that the vector can be of `factor` type, so even that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `help(LogitBoost)` examples section, `Label = iris[, 5]` results in a vector, as expected in the `ylearn` argument to `LogitBoost()`.

In your code, `label_train <- train %>% dplyr::select(.data = ., !!rlang::enquo(x))` results in a data.frame. `dplyr`, by design, defaults to `drop = FALSE` (and even ignores the argument) when only one column is selected.

We could do:

```
logit_model <- caTools::LogitBoost(xlearn = data_train, ylearn = dplyr::pull(label_train))
```